# How do I scrape elements at the same level from a website using bs4

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this list of books and authors from the following site:

https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/sep/21/best-books-of-the-21st-century

I first make a soup object using:
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')

Then I inspect the specific element on chrome, and filter in on the specific part of the page by:

listicle = soup.find('div', class_='content__article-body from-content-api js-article__body')

Now, for the parts that are confusing:

1. The list has the index, the book title, and the author name all at the same level (h2). I can do a find('h2') to get to 'index' and then try to access the rest with next_sibling. Is there a better way?
2. Even if I figure out No. 1 above, I need to write a 'for-loop' to get to the rest of the entries in the listicle? I can't seem to figure out how to do that as the 'listicle' variable that I created only contains a list and it wouldn't necessarily list through each entry (book 1, book 2, etc.) but through each element in the list(book 1 index, book 1 author, etc.).

I am completely new to web-scraping. So apologies if this is a very dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use select all `<h2>` and use `zip()` function. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/sep/21/best-books-of-the-21st-century'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

h2s = soup.select('.content__article-body h2')[::-1]   # we want go in ascending fashion
for author, title, i in zip(h2s[::3], h2s[1::3], h2s[2::3]):
    print('{:<5} {:<60} {}'.format(i.text, title.text, author.text))
```

Prints:

```
1     Wolf Hall                                                    by Hilary Mantel (2009)
2     Gilead                                                       by Marilynne Robinson (2004)
3     Secondhand Time                                              by Svetlana Alexievich (2013), translated by Bela Shayevich (2016)
4     Never Let Me Go                                              by Kazuo Ishiguro (2005)
5     Austerlitz                                                   by WG Sebald (2001), translated by Anthea Bell (2001)
6     The Amber Spyglass                                           by Philip Pullman (2000)
7     Between the World and Me                                     by Ta-Nehisi Coates (2015)
8     Autumn                                                       by Ali Smith (2016)
9     Cloud Atlas                                                  David Mitchell (2004)
10    Half of a Yellow Sun                                         by Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie (2006)
11    My Brilliant Friend                                          by Elena Ferrante (2011), translated by Ann Goldstein (2012)
12    The Plot Against America                                     by Philip Roth (2004)
13    Nickel and Dimed                                             by Barbara Ehrenreich (2001)
14    Fingersmith                                                  by Sarah Waters (2002)
15    The Sixth Extinction                                         by Elizabeth Kolbert (2014)
16    The Corrections                                              by Jonathan Franzen (2001)
17    The Road                                                     by Cormac McCarthy (2006)
18    The Shock Doctrine                                           by Naomi Klein (2007)
19    The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night‑Time            by Mark Haddon (2003)
20    Life After Life                                              by Kate Atkinson (2013)
21    Sapiens                                                      by Yuval Noah Harari (2011), translated by Harari with John Purcell and Haim Watzman (2014)
22    Tenth of December                                            by George Saunders (2013)
23    The Noonday Demon                                            by Andrew Solomon (2001)
24    A Visit from The Goon Squad                                  by Jennifer Egan (2011)
25    Normal People                                                by Sally Rooney (2018)
26    Capital in the Twenty First Century                          by Thomas Piketty (2013), translated by Arthur Goldhammer (2014)
27    Hateship, Friendship, Courtship, Loveship, Marriage          by Alice Munro (2001)
28    Rapture                                                      by Carol Ann Duffy (2005)
29    A Death in the Family                                        by Karl Ove Knausgaard (2009), translated by Don Bartlett (2012)
30    The Underground Railroad                                     by Colson Whitehead (2016)
31    The Argonauts                                                by Maggie Nelson (2015)
32    The Emperor of All Maladies                                  by Siddhartha Mukherjee (2010)
33    Fun Home                                                     by Alison Bechdel (2006)
34    Outline by Rachel                                            Cusk (2014)
35    The Hare with Amber Eyes                                     by Edmund de Waal (2010)
36    Experience                                                   by Martin Amis (2000)
37    The Green Road                                               by Anne Enright (2015)
38    The Line of Beauty                                           by Alan Hollinghurst (2004)
39    White Teeth                                                  by Zadie Smith (2000)
40    The Year of Magical Thinking                                 by Joan Didion (2005)
41    Atonement                                                    by Ian McEwan (2001)
42    Moneyball                                                    by Michael Lewis (2010)
43    Citizen: An American Lyric                                   by Claudia Rankine (2014)
44    Hope in the Dark                                             by Rebecca Solnit (2004)
45    Levels of Life                                               by Julian Barnes (2013)
46    Human Chain                                                  by Seamus Heaney (2010)
47    Persepolis                                                   by Marjane Satrapi (2000-2003), translated by Mattias Ripa (2003-2004)
48    Night Watch                                                  by Terry Pratchett (2002) 
49    Why Be Happy When You Could Be Normal?                       by Jeanette Winterson (2011)
50    Oryx and Crake                                               by Margaret Atwood (2003)
51    Brooklyn                                                     by Colm Tóibín (2009)
52    Small Island                                                 by Andrea Levy (2004)
53    True History of the Kelly Gang                               by Peter Carey (2000)
54    Women & Power                                                by Mary Beard (2017)
55    The Omnivore’s Dilemma                                       by Michael Pollan (2006)
56    Underland                                                    by Robert Macfarlane (2019)
57    The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier and Clay                  by Michael Chabon (2000)
58    Postwar                                                      by Tony Judt (2005)
59    The Beauty of the Husband                                    by Anne Carson (2002)
60    Dart                                                         by Alice Oswald (2002)
61    This House of Grief                                          by Helen Garner (2014)
62    Mother’s Milk                                                by Edward St Aubyn (2006)
63    The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks                         by Rebecca Skloot (2010)
64    On Writing                                                   by Stephen King (2000)
65    Gone Girl                                                    by Gillian Flynn (2012)
66    Seven Brief Lessons on Physics                               by Carlo Rovelli (2014)
67    The Silence of the Girls                                     by Pat Barker (2018)
68    The Constant Gardener                                        by John le Carré (2001)
69    The Infatuations                                             by Javier Marías (2011), translated by Margaret Jull Costa (2013)
70    Notes on a Scandal                                           by Zoë Heller (2003)
71    Jimmy Corrigan: The Smartest Kid on Earth                    by Chris Ware (2000)
72    The Age of Surveillance Capitalism                           by Shoshana Zuboff (2019)
73    Nothing to Envy                                              by Barbara Demick (2009)
74    Days Without End                                             by Sebastian Barry (2016)
75    Drive Your Plow Over the Bones of the Dead                   by Olga Tokarczuk (2009), translated by Antonia Lloyd-Jones (2018)
76    Thinking, Fast and Slow                                      by Daniel Kahneman (2011)
77    Signs Preceding the End of the World                         by Yuri Herrera (2009), translated by Lisa Dillman (2015)
78    The Fifth Season                                             by NK Jemisin (2015)
79    The Spirit Level                                             by Richard Wilkinson and Kate Pickett (2009)
80    Stories of Your Life and Others                              by Ted Chiang (2002)
81    Harvest                                                      by Jim Crace (2013)
82    Coraline                                                     by Neil Gaiman (2002)
83    Tell Me How It Ends                                          by Valeria Luiselli (2016), translated by Luiselli with Lizzie Davis (2017)
84    The Cost of Living                                           by Deborah Levy (2018)
85    The God Delusion                                             by Richard Dawkins (2006)
86    Adults in the Room                                           by Yanis Varoufakis (2017)
87    Priestdaddy                                                  by Patricia Lockwood (2017)
88    Noughts & Crosses                                            by Malorie Blackman (2001)
89    Bad Blood                                                    by Lorna Sage (2000)
90    Visitation                                                   by Jenny Erpenbeck (2008), translated by Susan Bernofsky (2010)
91    Light                                                        by M John Harrison (2002)
92    The Siege                                                    by Helen Dunmore (2001)
93    Darkmans                                                     by Nicola Barker (2007)
94    The Tipping Point                                            by Malcolm Gladwell (2000)
95    Chronicles: Volume One                                       by Bob Dylan (2004)
96    A Little Life                                                by Hanya Yanagihara (2015)
97    Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire                          by JK Rowling (2000)
98    The Girl With the Dragon Tattoo                              by Stieg Larsson (2005), translated by Steven T Murray (2008)
99    Broken Glass                                                 by Alain Mabanckou (2005), translated by Helen Stevenson (2009)
100   I Feel Bad About My Neck                                     by Nora Ephron (2006)
```